# With Dart source code, is there an Object Oriented way to parse and modify it?

Tags: dart, code-generation, build-runner

The pseudo code for what I would like to do:

```
var classObject=Parse(templateFile);
classObject.functions.add(MyGeneratedFunction)
return classObject.toSourceCode()
```

I really feel like I'm missing something here.
I know I can use analysis to parse a file into a tree, but there doesn't seem to be a way to modify it.

I also know I can use code_builder to output source code, but there doesn't seem to be a way to input source code, and I can't walk or modify the tree once built.

I feel like the only path would be to create an intermediate tree from an analysis tree, modify the intermediate tree as needed, and than output a code_builder tree, but that's a LOT of overhead for something that feels like it should be a lot simpler.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Try this one out: https://github.com/dart-lang/code_builder. I doubt it is exactly what you are searching for, but maybe can help someway.